# Saving Data that never Changes Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7

I wanna create a table somehow in wondows phone that holds data that never changes and the application querys that data. Pretty simple but not sure how to do it.

Example

a table with Name, Description

When you open the app all the theres an input box to enter a name then you press a button and the description displays.

Using isolated storage seems like you are writing all the data to a file everytime the a user opens the app. Is that how it works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Using isolated storage seems like you are writing all the data to a file everytime the a user opens the app. Is that how it works?

No, IsolatedStorage is storage - you can think of it as "disk" - so everything in it is persisted between application runs.

When you first run your application, then you'll need to create your files there, but after that time, then the files will already be in place.

If you need to put a large amount of data into IsolatedStorage and then need to search that data later, then "lite" database solutions like http://sterling.codeplex.com/ or SqlLite might help

Comment: FYI, the emulator does not persist isolated storage if it is closed, which may cause some confusion into how IS works.

Answer (score 0):

For test purposes simply hard code the values as a dictionary.

In the long term I suggest you store the information as a file in isolated storage.

[Here](http://3water.wordpress.com/2010/08/07/isolated-storage-on-wp7-ii/) is an article that describes how to load and save data to isolated storage

Comment: I looked at that, im just a little foggy, so you have to write all the data to a file everytime a user opens the app? Is that how it works?

Comment: No. In the short term - for prototyping - just hard code the values using a dictionary. In the longer term you may want to be a bit smarter - check a web service to see if the values have changes on startup for example. If you do that you will then save to iso store and then load from the iso store. In my experience values that never change often change!